# ajax post - loading div contents, model validation not working

Tags: model, validation

My problem is that the Client side Model validation is not working when I am loading the contents of the div through an ajax call.

My Partial View returned from the ajax call is a View containing fields for MemberInfo and using MemberModel.

```
<div id="wizard">
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "wizard-form"}))
{
    <div data-bind="with: memberModel()">
        //content replaced thru ajax call
        <div id="wizard-content">
        </div>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Also using knockout for the text binding on my partial view with the javascript model.

var memberModel= ko.observable(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))),

I am posting my MemberModel to the controller method called from ajax which returns the MemberInfo Partial View:

```
    var data = ko.toJSON(memberModel());

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "" && data != null) {
                $("#wizard-content").html(data);
                ko.applyBindings(memberModel, document.getElementById("wizard"));
            }
        }
    });
```

MemberModel is like:

```
public class MemberModel
{        
    public int MemberID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string MemberName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s.,'-]{2,50}$"]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s.,'-]{2,50}$"]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

}

My knockout binding is working fine after loading the contents of Partial View. But the model validation for the form is not working on the view that is rendered.

Comment: I have also tried putting this code in the ajax success function:

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#wizard-form");

But this too doesnt help. Even I am rendering the jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive again for the view. But nothing works.

Form validation works when I render the view using @Html.Partial but doesnt when I load div content through ajax with .html(data)